# Angular 6 cannot automatically select/bind dropdown list value from supplied object

Tags: select, dropdown, angular6

I get a country object from a service and bind it to a form that has a dropdown list of countries. The country doesn't appear selected after retrieving it from the service but all the other data is shown OK including a string gender field which is bound to a dropdown list. I can manually select the country from the list though. How can I automatically show the country as selected?

personal-details.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="doSave(form.values)">
        <mat-card class="main-card">

            <mat-card-content>
                <p>Personal Details</p>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Given name" formControlName="givenName" >
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Surname" formControlName="surname" required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
                    <mat-select placeholder="Select gender" formControlName="gender" required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let g of genders" [value]="g">{{g}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>      
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
                    <mat-select placeholder="Select country of birth" formControlName="countryBorn" required>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>      
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-card-content>

        </mat-card>
    </form>
```

personal-details.component.ts

```
  countries = [
    new Country('1100', 'Australia', '1'),
    new Country('1201', 'New Zealand', '160'),
    new Country('3105', 'Malta', '140')
  ];
  genders = ['F', 'M'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      givenName: ['', Validators.required],
      surname: ['', Validators.required],
      gender: ['', Validators.required],
      countryBorn: ''
    });

    this.response = this.applicantService.getDetails()
      .pipe(take(1), tap(resp => {
        this.form.patchValue(resp.personalDetails);
      }));

  }
```

domains:

```
export class PersonalDetails {
  givenName: string;
  surname: string;
  gender: string;
  countryBorn: Country;

  constructor(givenName?: string, surname?: string, gender?: string, countryBorn?: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.countryBorn = countryBorn;
  }
}  

export class Country {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  displayOrder: string;

  constructor(id?: string, name?: string, displayOrder?: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
  }
}
```

data:

```
incoming value from service: { "surname": "Oliver", "givenName": "Bert", "gender": "M", "countryBorn": { "id": "1201", "name": "New Zealand", "displayOrder": "160" }, "birthdate": "1990-04-21" }

Form value on load ({{form.value | json }}) =  { "givenName": "Bert", "surname": "Oliver", "gender": "M", "countryBorn": { "id": "1201", "name": "New Zealand", "displayOrder": "160" }
```

Thanks

Comment: This question is being asked every other day. Country object in your person, even if it has the same properties as one of the countries in the array of countries, is not `===` to any of them. It needs to be. Find the country of the array that has the same ID as the country in the person, and replace the person's country by that country from the array. Or just use the country ID as the value for your select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular uses object identity to select option and also provides special input property to customize the default option comparison algorithm: **[compareWith](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)**:

**html**

```
<mat-select ... formControlName="countryBorn" [compareWith]="compareFn">
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**ts**

```
compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country) {
  return c1.id === c2.id;
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/WqS30UrWx8pldCPFqEPz)**

Comment: Fantastic! spent so much time on this and thanks to you it's working. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Either Set **resp.personalDetails.countryBorn** to the actual object from list before assigning it to form (since object comparison {...}==={...} is always false, Angular won't be able to match and select on it)

```
resp.personalDetails.countryBorn = this.countries.find(country=> resp.personalDetails.countryBorn.id);
```

or set id alone as value

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
```

The data would have only country ID not whole object.

```
{ "surname": "Oliver", "givenName": "Bert", "gender": "M", "countryBorn": "1201", "name": "New Zealand", "displayOrder": "160" }, "birthdate": "1990-04-21" }
```

or else you may need to define your own comparison function using **compareWith**: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection